# Inconsistent saveAsTextFiles when using mapWithState in spark streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, duplicates, spark-streaming

To identify duplicate records i am using mapWithState with my row RDD. The code is supposed to check the state of each key it receives and return value and the state. Looking at the key i should be able to identify if i already processed the key(duplicate) or if it is a new key even across rdds in a dstream.

Here is the relevant part of my code.

```
object StreamingDeduplicate{
def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("StreamingDeduplication")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Minutes(2))
    ssc.checkpoint("streamingDedupCheckpoint")
    val input = ssc.textFileStream("/test/spark/deduplicate")
    val rowRdd = input.map(line => (line.split(",")(0), line))

    val checkIfKeyExists = (key: String, value: Option[String], state: State[String]) => {
      val currentState =  state.getOption.getOrElse("new")
      state.update("existing")
      //value is the whole record
      (value, currentState)
    }
    val checkDuplicates = rowRdd.mapWithState(StateSpec.function(checkIfKeyExists))

    // STORE:1
    checkDuplicates.saveAsTextFiles("/test/spark/out_all")
    // STORE:2
    rowRdd.saveAsTextFiles("/test/spark/out_temp")

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(1000*60*10)
}}
```

The issue i am facing is when i run it and feed some files, in one run it picks up a few of them and the next time i clear the input files and clear the checkpoint and then feed it the same files it might pick fewer records or more records than the first time and it is not consistent.

Another finding is that when i COMMENT STORE1 and run i can see the same number of records in output(location2) as in input. this verifies that spark is able to pick up all the newly placed files but when i UNCOMMENT both i get the same behaviour as explained above.

The following would regenerate the issue in my environment

1. Delete both the output directories(/test/spark/out_duplicates and /test/spark/out_new)
2. Clear the checkpoint location(./streamingDedupCheckpoint)
3. Clear the streaming input folder(/test/spark/deduplicate)
4. Submit the spark job(spark-submit  --master yarn-cluster  --class  "com.datametica.warehouse.deduplication.StreamingDeduplicate" Spark_DW-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar)
5. Once the application state changes to running copy a bunch of new files of a total of few hundred MB to /test/spark/deduplicate(i made sure the copy completes within first two minutes)

Here are some 3 sample records from one of the the input data files

```
705,2320,Ron,64
111,2326,Sienna,29
918,3678,Morton,45
```

Comment: When operating on RDDs, the data is split into partitions and distributed. By the look of it, your checkIfKeyExists is executed locally on each partition, so the result will not be deterministic (it depends how the data is shuffled).

Comment: Storing the incoming data in one of the various storage systems either integrated with or connected to spark would allow you to check for duplicates.

Comment: *The issue i am facing is when i run it and feed some files, in one run it picks up a few of them and the next time i clear the input files and clear the checkpoint and then feed it the same files it might pick fewer records or more records than the first time and it is not consistent.* Can you please provide us the relevant test data and the actual steps to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @ Yuval Itzchakov. I have edited the question with the info you requested see if this helps you unnderstand my question

Comment: @ psoucy . I guess you're true i might have to look at how my records are getting distributed. The current logic might show some existing records as new because of the wrong distribution but it still has to generate as many records as there are in the input because there is no operation which could drop any records


@plambre . You mean storing to say HDFS without using mapWithState? i am not clear on how to do that.

Comment: @Hemanthmeka There are a bunch: [SnappyData](https://github.com/SnappyDataInc/snappydata), [MemSQL](https://github.com/memsql/memsql-spark-connector), [hBase](https://github.com/nerdammer/spark-hbase-connector), [redis](https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis), [cassandra](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector). Taking SnappyData as an example, you could store the incoming data in a row table using SQL/or a DataFrame.forEach then check the row table for existence every time a new microbatch arrives, discarding duplicates